# Clojure or Scheme bayesian classification libraries?

Tags: clojure, scheme, racket, bayesian

Any pointers to scheme/racket or clojure bayesian classification libraries? I need one for a toy/learning project that I'm going to do.

Comment: A huge part of the value of Clojure is that it can use any Java library. So don't restrict yourself from searching in the Java only world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For clojure there is [Incanter.](http://incanter.org/) It's more than just a bayes library. It is more akin to [R](http://www.r-project.org/). The documentation has two sections about it's bayes capabilities: [1](http://data-sorcery.org/2009/07/01/bayes-multinomial/), [2](http://wiki.github.com/liebke/incanter/statistics-examples#wiki-blinreg).

Answer (score 3):

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is kind of classic. It is a Java lib, so it can be accessed from Clojure

Answer (score 2):

If you use Clojure, you have full access to Java libraries. [Classifier4J](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/) seems to be a good fit, although development stopped several years ago. You should be able to find several more if you dig through Sourceforge (not sure what your specific requirements are).

Answer (score 0):

There's also https://github.com/psantacl/naive-bayes-clj